# "You can’t post new questions right now"

Tags: discussion, questions

While trying to post, I'm receiving:

> Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from your account because
> most of your questions need improvement or are out of scope for this
> site. See the Help Center page Why are questions no longer being
> accepted from my account? to learn more.
>
> Please do not create a new account. Instead, work on improving your
> existing questions by editing them to comply with the site's
> guidelines and address any feedback you've received. You can also
> continue to contribute to the site in other ways, such as editing
> other posts to improve them.

I went over my 9 questions, and I don't see anything exceptional or know how to improve them.

None of this is reflected in my score and badges.

Answer (score 6):

You have [5 deleted questions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/deleted-questions/127053), some of which have a negative score. Those get deleted automatically if they aren't answered. You get the reputation back you lost from them, but they still count towards the question ban; see [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/295232)

I don't see a quick way to improve those questions either, so I hope this works:

> If you're blocked from asking questions and are unable to improve your existing questions (or your existing questions are all deleted), you'll get the chance to post one new question 6 months after your last question. Your block will still remain once that question is posted, but a single positively-received question could be enough to lift you out of the block. (This does not apply to answer bans.)

FWIW, there's no way for ♦ moderators or staff to lift the ban - it's a purely automatic process.

Comment: To summarize: I can't post for the next 6 months due to poor judgement of the moderators that resulted in the bot suspending me.

Comment: It wouldn't have been a problem if you hadn't posted [duplicate](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/289739) or [clearly off-topic](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/322304/18673) questions - please don't blame others or the system.

Comment: I agree about the duplicate (although, it wasn't a duplicate but a "bump up," which proved to be effective--I got an answer on the original thread). "Clearly off-topic"--not clearly at all: there are questions on the website regarding cursive writing. Even if these two aren't acceptable, two bad questions, and I'm suspended? Not very friendly. And what's up anyway with the we all bow to the mighty bot, and no one can override it.

Comment: OK, maybe not too clearly, but still ... Again, it also wouldn't have been a problem if you had more upvoted questions. Did you get a warning before posting your last question, as described in the FAQ? It has been a while, you might not remember ...

Comment: Wait, you probably haven't, otherwise I'd [be able to see it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278817/295232). Then it's bad luck with the timing of the automatic deletions. I agree the algorithm can be harsh, but we really need it for some notorious problem users, and on [so] the situation is much worse ...

Comment: English Language for Learners has nowhere near the same volume of low-quality questions that SO has. **2,140,329 questions have been posted on SO** since 2009, but the total number of questions (excluding deletions) posted **on ELL is 103,997** . If the user did not receive *any* warning the fault *does* lie with the system. But if the user *did* receive a warning, which they willingly chose to ignore,  than that's their fault.

Comment: Maybe, yeah. I just cast two upvotes, perhaps that will help a bit?

Comment: I can ask now; thanks.

Comment: You're welcome - please make it count :)